# Different look at iPhone 8 and iPhone X

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios12

There is a problem with the text view that's been programmatically created. It just pops up to ~20px at iPhoneX, but looks perfect at iPhone 8. I'll be super grateful for any hints :) Screenshots attached.

iPhoneX:
http://prntscr.com/lcnh2y 
iPhone 8:
http://prntscr.com/lcnhns

Code:

```
let rect = CGRect(x: 20, y: self.tabsSegmentedControl.layer.position.y + 20, width: self.tabsSegmentedControl.layer.frame.width, height: 127)
    self.ingredientsTextView = UITextView(frame: rect)
    ingredientsTextView.isEditable = false
    ingredientsTextView.isSelectable = false
    self.view.addSubview(ingredientsTextView)
```

Comment: How _tabsSegmentedControl_ is created by code or programatically?

Comment: tabsSegmentedControl is created at Storyboard editor. It has all proper constrains in place.

Comment: Can you post the code where you're adding constraint to the textview?

Comment: There are no specific constrains for textview. It's positioned at the code above. 
Only segmentedBar has constrains now. And textview taking self.tabsSegmentedControl.layer.position.y + 20 as it's Y value

Comment: Please share the screenshot of how the constraints are added to _tabsSegmentedControl_

Comment: In which method you are adding this textview?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/lcoc0j

Comment: The method I'm using to add textView is written in initial post. That's the only code for it's creation and it's used at viewDidLoad()

Comment: Use viewWillLayoutSubviews() method to add textview. It may be solve your problem.

Comment: No don't use `viewWillLayoutSubviews` to add anything.  Only use it to actually layout the subviews if you need to.  The problem you are probably getting is that the segmented control is getting it's position adjusted due to the safe area but that is happening after the text view has been setup so the frame is incorrect.  I would suggest using constraints for the text view instead of a fixed frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use viewDidLoad for Creation and WillLayout for positioning.
I don't recommend mixing Storyboard and programmatically creation of the UI

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var tabsSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!

var ingredientsTextView : UITextView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    ingredientsTextView = UITextView(frame: .zero)
    self.view.addSubview(ingredientsTextView)
    ingredientsTextView.isEditable = false
    ingredientsTextView.isSelectable = false
}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    let rect = CGRect(x: 20, y: self.tabsSegmentedControl.frame.maxY + 20, width: self.tabsSegmentedControl.frame.width, height: 127)
    ingredientsTextView.frame = rect
    ingredientsTextView.text = "There is a problem with the text view that's been programmatically created. It just pops up to ~20px at iPhoneX, but looks perfect at iPhone 8. I'll be super grateful for any hints :) Screenshots attached."
}
```

}